# How to p4add or p4edit, as appropriate, a file?

Tags: ant, perforce

I'm using the Perforce tasks for Ant and would like to  a file if it's not already known to Perforce or  it if it is.

I can:

```
<p4add changelist='${p4.change}' failonerror='false'>
    <fileset file='my-file'/>
</p4add>
<p4edit changelist='${p4.change}'>
    <fileset file='my-file'/>
</p4edit>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<trycatch property='my-file-is-new'><try>
    <p4edit view='my-file'/>
</try><catch>
    <touch file='my-file'/>
    <p4add>
        <fileset file='my-file'/>
    </p4add>
</catch></trycatch>

<if><isset property="my-file-is-new"/><then>
    <echo message="p4 added my-file"/>
</then><else>
    <echo message="p4 edited my-file"/>
</else></if>
```

Answer (score 0):

The p4fstat task can filter based on a file's status in the repository.  It seems like a cleaner approach but may take more lines of Ant script.

Comment: How can the script act on the information from p4fstat? There doesn't seem to be a way to put the info into a property or resource.